# What is removable discontinuity for a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

Can someone tell me the removable discontinuity and poles of a function in complex analysis?

I read the definition in the book but I cannot feel it. Is there a nice definition?

Comment: What definition have you read?

Answer (score 3):

The situation is just like the reals.  A removable discontinuity is something like $\frac {z^2-4}{z+2}$ at $z=-2$.  The function is not defined there, but there is a limit.  If you just define the function to be $-4$ at $z=-2$ you have the function $z-2$, which is nicely continuous.  A pole is something like $\frac 1{z^n}$ at $z=0$  for some natural $n$.  The modulus of the function heads off to infinity as you approach the point.

Comment: thanks is the pole means the limit does not exist at that point

Comment: That is correct, but usually it is more restrictive.  There are many ways the limit might not exist, but a pole has to be of this form.  There can be terms in the MacLauren expansion like $\frac 1{z^m}$ for $m \lt n$, but the function has to be analytic near the pole.  Not all functions are.  Usually essential singularities like $\exp(\frac 1z)$ at $z=0$ are also excluded.

Answer (score 1):

A function, f, is "continuous" at z= a if and only if

1) f(a) exists

2) $\lim_{z\to a} f(x)$ exists

3) $\lim_{z\to a} f(x)= f(a)$

A function, f, has a "removable discontinuity" at z= a if and only if 
$\lim_{z\to a} f(x)$ exists but f(a) either does not exist or exist but does not equal $\lim_{z\to a} f(x)$.  We can "remove" the discontinuity by redefining f(a) to equal $\lim_{a\to a} f(x)$.  An example is $f(z)= z^2$ for all $z\ne a$, f(0)= 1.

A function, f, has a "pole" at z= a if and only if it is expanded in a Laurent series (essentially a Taylor's series except that it can include negative powers) there is a largest (in absolute value) negative exponent. If that "largest (in absolute value) negative exponent" is "-n" then the discontinuity is a "pole of order n" An example is $f(z)= \frac{1}{z-1}$ which has a "pole of order 1" at z= 1. $f(z)= \frac{1}{(z- 1)^3}$ has a pole of order 3 at z= 1.

A function, f, can also have an "essential discontinuity" at z= a if and only if when you expand it in a Laurent series, it has infinitely many negative powers.  An example is $f(z)= e^{\frac{1}{z}}$.  The **analytic** function, $e^z$, can be expanded in the Taylor's series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$.  We can get the Laurent series for $e^{\frac{1}{z}}= e^{z^{-1}}$ by replacing z by $z^{-1}$:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-n}}{n!}$.